# cannot access an array of objects returned from api call in react

Tags: arrays, reactjs, axios, superagent

I have an API call, that is called multiple times inside a map function to retrieve nested data from **mongodb**.

The results are pushed to an array. 
The array is used as props data for a child component.

I can `console.log()` the resulting array. but I cannot access it in react, or iterate through it.

Does anyone know how to sort this problem. It should work. I can't see any reason for it not to. It's becoming very frustrating

```
fetchMemory(props) {
  const tempMemories = [];
  if (props.journey) {
    props.journey.memories.map((mem) = > {
      superagent
        .get(`/memories/$ {
          mem
        }`)
        .end(function (err, res) {
          let tp = res.body
          tempMemories.push(tp)
        });
    })
    this.setState({
      memories: tempMemories
    })
  }
}
```

I cannot access the array of memories returned in setstate. they do show up if you inspect them in the console/ It just returns an error, in the child component (as props).

> "TypeError: Cannot read property 'memories' of undefined"

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Fetch data via axios is async, so basically `tempMemories` will be empty in your call to setState(), because the network calls aren't completed yet.

You should use `Promise.all` like this:

```
const promiseList = props.journey.memories.map( mem => {
  return superagent
     .get(`/memories/${mem}`)
     .then( res => res.body );
});

Promise.all( promiseList )
  .then( results => {
    this.setState({
      memories: results
    });
  })
  .catch( err => {
    ...
  });
```

So basically you create one promise for each element and then wait for all of them to get resolved to do the `setState()` call.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! It really helped.